# What is the nicest way to say "old person" while still being polite and non-offensive?

Tags: word-choice

So I was working on a presentation and I was using the word elderly, but the evidence I was using had the word senior in it. And I was thinking that the word elderly was polite and non-offensive, but now I am not sure. Any ideas on what word is non-offensive and polite?

Comment: @Laurel - The only answer there is “along in years”.  Not a very good option in my opinion.  I think *seniors*  is the best option.